# Is there a way to jump to the target/scheme selection menu in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I know the keyboard shortcuts for most things I often do in Xcode, but there is one thing I still haven't figured out:

How do I switch the active target/scheme without using my mouse?

I can switch from the previous and next scheme by using CTRL+COMMAND+[, but I would really like to expand the menu and type the scheme I want, similarly to how I can expand the methods navigator with CTRL+6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl+0` will show a list of schemes. Then all you need to do is type a name of a scheme and hit enter.